# MVC 3 Error for Navigating between Models in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I've been stuck in this issue for the whole afternoon, appreciate if anyone can tell me how, Thanks!

I am using MVC 3 and setup two models:

```
public class Employee
    {
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Emp_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Emp_Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }

public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string SO { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Manhour_Type { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? StartJob { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? EndJob { get; set; }
    public virtual double? Duration { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee employee { get; set; }
}
```

Two databases are generated by this code:

```
public class JMCDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasRequired(j => j.employee).WithMany(e => e.Jobs);
    }
}
```

I Create the JobController as follows:

```
public class JobController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Job/

    JMCDB _db = new JMCDB();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var job = _db.Jobs;
        return View(job);
    }
 }
```

In "View", I wanna see the employee name of this specific job:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SO)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manhour_Type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartJob)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndJob)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employee.Emp_Name)
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    </tr>
}
```

But when I run the program, there is an error for the last line of code

```
"@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employee.Emp_Name)"
```

I don't know how to solve, Thanks if anyone can tell me how.

Comment: Could you please provide more source code ? How do you "load" your entity and what is the exception message ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Include` method to eager load the navigational property `employee`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var job = _db.Jobs.Include(job => job.employee);
    return View(job);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, though I haven't figured out why. But really appreciated!